# Json - Serializing Property in the response as a Different Type

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a `String` field in my POJO like this:

```
private String code; // code can be "111", "CD", "XX", etc.
```

Is there some JSON annotation that would allow serializing this field as Number (i.e. `int`), but **only** if the property can be converted from `String` into `int`?

*Example*

If code is number, expected response:

```
{
    "code": 111
}
```

Else, if it is text:

```
{
    "code": "CD"
}
```

Right now both come out as string "111", "CD", etc.

Comment: I want to generate this as response. right now the number comes out as string as well. "code": "111".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a custom serializer by extending abstract class [`JsonSerializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer.html#method_summary), and provide it via `using` attribute of the [`@JsonSerialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonSerialize.html) annotation, placed on the `code` field.

To discriminate between the cases when property can be represented as an `int` you can use a regular expression `"\\d+"`.

*Example:*

```
public class Foo {
    @JsonSerialize(using = StringToIntSerializer.class)
    private String code;
    // other fields
    
    // getter, setters, etc.
}

public static class StringToIntSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator gen,
                          SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
    
        if (value.matches("\\d+")) gen.writeNumber(value);
        else gen.writeString(value);
    }
}
```